# Android Studio 2.2 cannot Run a homescreen project

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio to 2.2. And now I cannot RUN or DEBUG my old **custom Homescreen** project. It always throws **No Default Activity**. I can still built an APK and deploy it to either emulator or real device, but this thing never happened before.

My manifest for this homescreen project is like below

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

I have to change my manifest to something like below In order to make it RUN-ABLE from Android Studio, but my project is now become a non **Homescreen** app.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Please anybody who has this problem and managed to make it work?

P.S. I use [this](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/) tutorial as my reference in building a custom homescreen project

**Is this Android Studio's bug????**

Thanks in advance.

**My log console is like below pic**

[image]

Comment: Can you please share error log ?

Comment: Hi Haresh, I just update my post with a screen capture of my log console with my manifest. ... If I comment out HOME and un comment LAUNCHER, it will run smooth ... but my project will no longer a homescreen project.

Comment: Is this just me? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to choose Specified Activity in Launch options inside Run/Debug Configuration!

BR